# Is it legal to position an at-rule inside a style block?

Tags: css, media-queries

The following is valid CSS:

```
@media print {
    .no_print {
        display: none;
    }
}
h1 {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

In the following I have placed an `@media` statement inside the `h1` style block. Is it valid CSS? Googling, I only find examples of `@media` statements being placed inside one another. I lack sufficient familiarity with the terminology of CSS to refine my search terms further in the hope of answering this question.

```
h1 {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    @media print {
        font-weight: normal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not valid. Generally, [at-rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#at-rules) (rules that begins with `@`) are allowed at the start of a style sheet only, by general CSS principles. However, `@media` and `@page` rules are allowed elsewhere, too, but only *between rules*, not inside a rule. A *rule* is a construct that consists of a list of selectors and a set of declarations between braces, e.g. `h1 { color: blue; line-height: 1 }`. Browsers are required to ignore a misplaced at-rule (and they do).

You could put the `@media` rule at the start, but to restrict the effect to `h1` elements you would need to specify it in the selector. Due to CSS cascade rules (which ignore media restrictiong in calculating specificity), you need to make that selector more specific than a mere `h1` (otherwise the latter declaration wins); a simple way is to use the contextual selector `body h1`, which does not restrict the meaning of the selector, just gives it highet specificity:

```
@media print {
    body h1 {
        font-weight: normal;
    }
}
h1 {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

If you don’t put all at-rules at the start, you can make the `@media` rule simpler:

```
h1 {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
@media print {
    h1 {
        font-weight: normal;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are exceptions to this rule - `@media` rules can be placed anywhere in a stylesheet and the cascade will take effect accordingly. They are, however, required to be placed outside of style rules. In this case, it's perfectly fine to have `@media print { h1 { font-weight: normal; } }` underneath the generic `h1` rule without having to use a specificity hack or `!important`.

Comment: Right, forgot that. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

No. This will invalidate your code, try it this on the w3 validator to check for yourself. http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

Comment: out of topic: I LOLed when I read OP ... reminded me of 4chan and reddit. +1 for the answer and the laugh :D

Comment: Well yeah: "OP" means Original Poster so it's not exactly unique to 4chan or reddit. There is hardly ever a need to address the asker in an answer though - you are answering the asker's question so naturally you would be writing to them.

Comment: Sorry about that BoltClock, English is my second language and I am working on improving it, not meant as a sign of disrespect when I addressed the poster of this question.